# UML Designer in linux

Tags: linux, uml

I work with Umbrello but it hasn't some feature that i need and Umbrello is not good tools for class diagram .
what other tools exist in Linux ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/). It's available for Linux, Windows and Mac OS.

Answer (score 2):

[BOUML](http://bouml.free.fr/) is referred to in this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960432/uml-how-to-manage-big-class-diagrams) (besides some other answers).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is also [StarUML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarUML) with a successor called [SunUML](http://sunuml.sourceforge.net/).

> **StarUML** supports most of the diagram types specified in UML 2.0. It is currently missing object, package, timing and interaction overview diagrams (though the first two can be adequately modeled through the class diagram editor).
>
> StarUML was written in Delphi, which is one of the reasons why it is no longer maintained.
> The project **SunUML** is aiming at creating a successor based on StarUML.

Comment: -1 for unjustified Delphic cruelty.

Comment: @Peter, Gee, thanks for serving justice on that quote `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

Try Visual Paradigm. It has free and paid versions for Windows, Mac, and Linux.

http://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpumluserguide/12/14/6043_linuxandunix.html